# about creating hash with certain keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I am lost. I need to create a hash with keys corresponding to numbers from 1 to 10. The result should be something like this:

```
my_hash = {1 => "", 2 => "", 3 => ""...}
```

I have

```
h = Hash.new
```

please give me at least one way of doing that, I will need "values" later, for now I just need a hash with keys and I will push values later. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but for hashes, no value, no key. You can change the values later but you can't have a barren key hanging out in a hash. If `keys = [1,2,3]`, maybe `h = keys.product('').to_h #=> {1=>"", 2=>"", 3=>""}`. You should reconsider whether you need such a hash, as opposed to creating the hash when you have at least one key-value pair to add.

Comment: i am sorry, I was so frustrated with such simple task that my question was not clear. I will need this hash in variable length depending on another input, but always ordered integers. thank you

Comment: Whoops! In my earlier comment I meant `keys.product([''])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = Hash.new
(1..10).each {|count| h[count] = ''}
```

Comment: thank you exactly what I needed. I have tried different loops, like '.upto' and 'for' but somehow could not manage to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
(1..10).map { |x| [x, ''] }.to_h
```

Or:

```
{}.tap { |h| 1.step(10) { |i| h[i] = '' } }
```

Or:

```
(1..10).zip(Array.new(10) { '' }).to_h
```

Comment: all works, all keys are in numerical order. Great examples, but i will need to study them to understand! Ruby is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

A few more options:

```
(1..10).each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = '' }
10.times.each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i + 1] = '' }
1.upto(10).each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = '' }

# Or if you think each_with_object is heresy...
(1..10).inject({}) { |h, i| h.merge!(i => '') } # merge! to avoid wasteful copying
10.times.inject({}) { |h, i| h.merge!(i + 1 => '') }
1.upto(10).inject({}) { |h, i| h.merge!(i => '') }
```